# Why is this made a property using a lambda function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, lambda, getter

From this page: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/html/page94.html

[image]

1. Why is `fget=lambda self: self.getNumberOfColumns()` used? I understand that this is to be able to use `Matrix().numberOfColumns` (as an attribute), but what is really happening here?
2. Why can't we do `fget=self.getNumberOfColumns()` instead of using the `lambda` function?

I am having a hard time understanding this. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `fget=self.getNumberOfColumns` because `self` isn't declared in the class scope.

However, the `lambda` isn't necessary; you can write it as

```
numberOfRows = property(fget=getNumberOfRows)
```

or, even better:

```
@property
def numberOfRows(self):
    return self._numberOfRows
```

without the need for an explicit getter, `property` call and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the lambda like this:

```
@property
def numberOfColumns(self):
    return self.getNumberOfColumns()
```

Comment: And I would use it in a client like this: `cols = Matrix().numberOfColumns`. Right?